# projecting future survival rate

Tags: r, survival, prediction, kaplan-meier

I'm working on a customer retention project that predicts the probability a customer is still subscribing to our services at time T. Unfortunately, we only have the most recent two years of customer data. Estimating the probability of survival at end of year 1 and 2 using Kaplan-Meier is straight-forward. But now we need to project the probability of survival at end of year 3, 4, and 5. Is it possible to do such a task using survival analysis or some other technique (preferably using R)?